# How to make PhpStorm access a proper directory?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm running Linux Mint. My existing projects are located at the `/var/www/*` folders. But when I'm trying to create a new project then the PhpStorm's file browser is not showing me that folder at all. Like there is just no `/var/www` folder, but I know it is there and is having a full access permissions (0777).

In addition it shows for example a folder `/var/data/JetBrains` which is not actually available in my system (terminal: `cd /var/data` - no such file or directory).

So it seems like it is showing some kind of its own `/var` folder (virtualized?), not the one that is actually in my system. How can I solve this problem, how can I make it so it use my system's `/var` folder?

[image: How PhpStorm sees it]
[image: What is in reality]

Comment: Try clicking on "Refresh" button in that dialog

Comment: No effect. Somehow any file/folder dialog in PhpStorm is showing some kind of crap - files and folders from I don't know where. The only folder that is showing proper data is my home directory. The rest is like virtualized or something. For example if I'm trying to find a CLI interpreter for the PHP then it is not listed at the /usr/bin/ in the PhpStorm's file dialog but in fact I have it there.

Comment: How did you installed PhpStorm? Snap, manual download from their website, JetBrains Toolbox App or something else? Try installing it differently: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/#section=linux

Comment: I've installed it using the Mint's built in program manager. It seems like that was the root of an evil. Downloading it from jetbrains' site directly solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Do not install the PhpStorm from the Mint's software manager. It comes there in some kind of wrapper that isolates the filesystem.